# using clang-format on a patch

Tags: version-control, clang, patch, clang-format

I tried clang-format and it works really well for my coding style. I wanted to know if it is possible to use clang format on just my patch so that I don't format  code which I don't want to modify. That way I could run clang-format on my patch before committing to the mainline.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

There is a patch to run clang-format on a diff:

http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html#script-for-patch-reformatting

It actually still formats the original files and only takes the diff to determine the line ranges it should run on.